What is a safe subset of SQL that can be exposed to a third-party, like support or customer?
A safe subset might be so small it's not usable, but still, would allowing only a certain character set be safe? What about white-listing certain tokens in the stream?
Example:
// Calculation for a SELECT column, input from user
$src = 'ROUND((1 - (purchase_price / selling_price)) * 100, 2)';
// Split into tokens
$tokens = token_get_all('<?php ' . $src);
// Validate all tokens by white-list, alphanumeric, or similar

The full query is constructed on server-side, including WHERE, FROM, LIMIT, etc.

An arbitrary query, even the simplest ones, will have the ability of starving resources from the server, unless it's throtled or dedicated to serve such queries. Take this query for example: SELECT * FROM billonRowTable CROSS JOIN billonRowTable, it'll eat thour all the server resources quite easily. As such, unless you control it in some way, my answer would be "none".

@Alejandro Sure, so don't allow 'SELECT' then? Or assume 'SELECT' and whitelist available tables? Also, as stated, the server will add LIMIT and WHERE-statements before running the query.

@Alejandro Perhaps true, but that's not what this question is about.

For the most part, the only safe and readily available option would be to use a prepared statement.  In a prepared statement, you can expose your SQL query via wildcards.  For example, consider this query:
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE purchase_price > ?;

To the ? placeholder you could bind some minimum purchase value coming from outside the database.
However, note that database objects (database, table, column names, etc.) cannot be represented by a ? placeholder.  Doing so would be a large security risk, as a malicious user could attempt to read from a table to which it should not have access.

I'm thinking even harder limitations, and only allow the SELECT column part, having everything else done by the server and not user.

@OlleHärstedt What do you mean "only allow the SELECT column part" this answer has a fixed column list?

@OlleHärstedt Yes you can build that, but you'll have to write code which sterlizes everything.

Forget about SQL!
Yes it was designed to be usable by an "ordinary business user" but it totally failed in that design goal.
What worked for me is to present some simple selection criteria and download the result to a spreadsheet. Techies hate them but users love them and are surprisingly adept at doing sophisticated calculation and analysis once they get their hands on base rows and columns.

Something like this you mean? https://querybuilder.js.org/

That would work for the base selection with suitable restrictions applied. But -- down load the results to a real Excel compatible spreadsheet file. Lots of libraries support building spreadsheets in the common back end languages.
